Remove rg-management Resource Group and Associated Policies in ALZ Setup
I recently attempted to apply a configuration to my Azure Landing Zone (ALZ) setup, which was implemented using the ALZ Accelerator, for testing purposes. However, I’ve encountered an issue when trying to remove the rg-management resource group. It appears that the policies applied during the ALZ Accelerator deployment are preventing its deletion.

I attempted to resolve this using a runbook example, but I received the following error message:

Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Managed System Identity not found! Status: 400 (Bad Request) Content: {"Message":"Managed System Identity not found!"} Headers: Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 02:13:40 GMT Server: Kestrel Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 See the troubleshooting guide for more information.

Could you please recommend a way to safely destroy the rg-management resource group and remove all associated policies created during this process?
